# floatによる回り込みをキャンセル

Tags: html, css

time2を`<div id="div3">`の下に表示したい。

条件：`<div id="div3">`の長さは任意なので、`<div id="div3" style="height:???px">`は利用できない

```html
    <body> 
    <div>
        <div>time1</div>
        <div style="float:right">2</div>
     <div id="div3" style="float:right">3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/></div> 
    </div>
    <div>
     <div>time2</div>
     <div style="float:left">4</div> 
     <div style="float:left">5</div> 
    </div> 
    </body>
```

Comment: time2が#div3の下に表示したい、

条件：#div3の長さは任意のて、height:??px利用できない

Comment: タグを表示するように修正しましたが、それでも助詞の扱いがおかしいなど日本語として内容を読み取れませんでした…

Comment: 日本語の初心者ですので、すみませんでした
suzukisさんの答え間違いないです
ありがとうございました

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSSで要素に`clear: both`を指定すればfloatによる回り込みをキャンセル出来ます。

```html
    <body> 
    <div>
        <div>time1</div>
        <div style="float:right">2</div>
     <div id="div3" style="float:right">3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/>3<br/></div> 
    </div>
    <div>
     <div style="clear: both">time2</div>
     <div style="float:left">4</div> 
     <div style="float:left">5</div> 
    </div> 
    </body>
```